# Optimize $\sum a_k x_k^2$ under the constraint $\sum x_k =c$, with $a_k > 0$

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

Optimization, under costraint  $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\sum a_k x_k^2$ under the constraint $\sum x_k =c$ with $a_k > 0,$ $k=1,\ldots,n$

The associated Lagrangian is : $L(x_1,\ldots, x_n)=f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)+ \lambda(\sum x_k -c)$

How to deduce that: $\lambda = \dfrac{-2c}{\sum \dfrac 1 {a_k}}$ and the value of $x_k$

**I can not show it, someone can help me thanks**

Comment: Very difficult to follow what you ask because no index is represented as an index. $a_k$ for example is obtained by typing five items: "dollar sign", "a", "underscore" symbol, then "k", then "dollar sign". Thanks to @Michael Hardy for fixing it...

Comment: Your Lagrangian had no $\lambda$ and one extra equality sign. Let me fix this.

Comment: @JeanMarie: I am not French, but "je approuve". Fixed this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differentiating the Lagrangian wrt to $x_k$ gives you
$$2a_k x_k + \lambda = 0 \qquad \mbox{for } k=1,\ldots,n$$
that yields
$$x_k = -\frac{\lambda}{2a_k} \mbox{for } $k=1,\ldots,n$$
Replace these in the constraint $\sum_k x_k = c$ to obtain
$$\lambda = - \frac{2c}{\sum_k (1/a_k)}$$
Plug $\lambda$ back into the equation for $x_k$ and get
$$x_k = c \left( \frac{(1/a_k)}{\sum_k (1/a_k)}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

You can also argue via Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. First, 
$$
\left(\sum_k a_k x_k^2 \right)\left(\sum_{k}\frac{1}{a_k}\right) \geq \left(\sum_k |x_k|\right)^2 \geq \left(\sum_k x_k\right)^2 = c^2.
$$

Equality holds if and only if, 
$$
\frac{a_k x_k^2}{\frac{1}{a_k}}
$$
is constant, namely if and only if, $x_k$ is proportional with $\frac{1}{a_k}$. Letting $x_k =\theta \frac{1}{a_k}$, we obtain
$$
\theta = \frac{c}{\sum_k \frac{1}{a_k}} \implies x_k = \frac{c\frac{1}{a_k}}{\sum_k \frac{1}{a_k}}.
$$